# modelling two one-to-many relationships database relationships in uml

Tags: database, uml, modeling

I have a database design with 3 tables, call them A, B and C, with the following one-to-many relationships:

```
A-<B>-C
```

Both A and B have an auto-incremented IDs as primary keys.

My problem is that if I have a record in table B which has a field containing an ID=12, for example, there is no way of knowing which of table A or C's primary keys this corresponds to. Both tables will have a primary key ID=12. I think this is an example of a fan trap, but any research I have done all relates to relationship such as:

```
A-<B-<C
```

and the solution is to restructure the tables. I'm not sure that this will work here. Do I need a table that sits between table B and tables A and C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that if I have a record in table B which has a field containing an ID=12, for example, there is no way of knowing which of table A or C's primary keys this corresponds to.

You have to add a column to B that lets you know whether the foreign key points to A or C.

Your other alternative is to have two nullable foreign keys in B, one pointing to A, and the other pointing to C.

I suspect that your tables could be normalized a bit more, so you have a structure like this:

```
                D
   --------------------------
   |            |           |
   A            B           C
  ---          ---         ---
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll probably go with having a column in B called something like 'set_by' and have it take values 'A' or 'B', and using this as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a foreign key to one of the tables to have that relationship.
In your example you would add the PK of table B as an FK in tables A, C